# What will happen if the AIDL files do not match?

Tags: android, service, client, aidl

I use **AIDL** in my Android app. Here are 2 cases where I have questions.

**Case 1**. aidl file of client has one method `a()`, and aidl file of service has 2 methods `a()` and `b()`.

Does it work normally? I've tested and didn't see any problem. The `binService()` method works normally.

**Case 2**. aid file of client has 2 methods `a()` and `b()`, but the aild file of service has only `a()` method.

The `binService()` method works. And we get crash when we call `b()` method in client. Here I thought the `binService` should not work, because the aidl service does not have method `b()`.

I want to make sure that the results I got are correct, and it always happens on all device.

Answer (score 0):

The results you got are correct. Also note that ordering is important for aidl files.

Example If you have 2 methods in client and service :

```
a()
b()
```

Then you added method `c()` in between

```
a()
c()
b()
```

In this case if you do not update the client with the updated aidl then calling method `b()` from client ends up calling `c()` in service - This is weird but this is how it seems to work (I had done by research on android 4.3 )